# vsdbcmd.exe generate drop constraint instructions without constraint name

Tags: sql-server, diff, vsdbcmd

When generating a diff script between two dbschema with vsdbcmd.exe, I sometime obtain an unexpected output, containing some drop constraint without the name of the constraint :

```
GO
PRINT N'Dropping On column: ColumnName ...';    

GO
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT ;
```

In our schema, this column has a default value constraint, with an auto generated name. I expected vsdbcmd.exe to generate a valid ALTER TABLE sql statement, as specified in the msdn library :

> ALTER TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name DROP { [ CONSTRAINT ] constraint_name | COLUMN column_name }

Do you have any idea of what could prevent vsdbcmd.exe to generate a valid sql statement ?

Comment: After further investigation, this only occurs when the constraint has an generated name. Explicitly named constrained are not impacted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue only occurs when the constraint has a generated name. Explicitly named constraint are not impacted.
Therefore, this solution is to name every constraint.